# Unnesting character string list and converting into wide data

Tags: r, tidyverse

I often have nested lists containing characters string in a tibble. I would like to convert this to long data attempts have been to transform it into wide data using the `tidyr` `unnest_wider` function, but I am unable to produce my desired results.
Suppose you have a dataframe with a nested character list like the following:

```r
#Producing a list with random character strings and embedding into dataframe.
set.seed(112)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
df$alist <- replicate(10, list(sample(letters[1:5],round(runif(1, min = 1, max = 5)))))
```

Using `tidyr::unnest_wider` almost gets me there, but I would like for the strings to go into the column names.

```r
df %>% unnest_wider(alist, names_sep = "_")
```

By using two `for` loops I´m able to achieve what I want:

```r
df %>% select(alist) %>% unlist(alist) %>% unique() %>% sort() %>% as.list() -> let

df[unlist(let)] <- NA

for(index in let) {
  
for (i in df$id){
  ifelse(index %in% df$alist[[i]],
         T,
         F) -> df[i,index]
  }
}
```

| id | alist | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b, d, a | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2 | a, b | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | d, a, c, e | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 4 | d, a, b, c | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 5 | a, c | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 6 | e | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 7 | c | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 8 | c, e, d | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 9 | a, d, e, c, b | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 10 | a | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

But frankly I am looking for a more elegant solution to the problem. I have the sense I am missing something obvious here...

Comment: Perhaps try: `df %>% tidyr::unnest(alist) %>% dplyr::arrange(id, alist) %>% dplyr::mutate(value = TRUE) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = alist, values_fill = FALSE)`

Comment: @ekoam. Thank you. This seems to work very well.

Comment: an excellent solution

Answer (score 1):

```r
set.seed(112)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
df$alist <-
  replicate(10, list(sample(letters[1:5], round(
    runif(1, min = 1, max = 5)
  ))))

library(tidyverse)

nm <- sort(unique(unlist(df$alist)))

bind_cols(df, map_df(
  .x = df$alist,
  .f = ~ purrr::set_names(x = nm %in% .x, nm = nm)
)) 
#>    id         alist     a     b     c     d     e
#> 1   1       b, d, a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 2   2          a, b  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 3   3    d, a, c, e  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> 4   4    d, a, b, c  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> 5   5          a, c  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> 6   6             e FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 7   7             c FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> 8   8       c, e, d FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> 9   9 a, d, e, c, b  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> 10 10             a  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest_longer(alist) %>%
  mutate(alist_2 = alist) %>% 
  complete(id, alist, fill = list(alist_2 = NA_character_)) %>% 
  mutate(present = if_else(is.na(alist_2), FALSE, TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-alist_2) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = alist,
    values_from = present
  ) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% select(alist))
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      id a     b     c     d     e     alist    
   <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <list>   
 1     1 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE <chr [3]>
 2     2 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE <chr [2]>
 3     3 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  <chr [4]>
 4     4 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE <chr [4]>
 5     5 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE <chr [2]>
 6     6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  <chr [1]>
 7     7 FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE <chr [1]>
 8     8 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  <chr [3]>
 9     9 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  <chr [5]>
10    10 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE <chr [1]>
```